# How to make a div display when <A> tag inside other div is hovered?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover

I'm trying to built a vertical menu inside a submenu container.

I have a horizontal menu with full width submenu container (this I have done, for the submenu content I need help)  - in which I would need to create a vertical drop-down menu, but the vertical-submenus need to appear in a div (or whatever will make it look like in the example) with the same height as the vertical menu, full width and appear in the same position no matter the parrent button's position. Hope you understood, if no just see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcx2LjsL/3/).

The problem is that the vertical menu container need to have a width of 20% and a specific color background and the container for its submenus should have the rest of 80% and a different color. On hover over one button (Button1) should appear that 80% width div (div.B.C) with its content (let's say a video).

```
<div class="AB">
<li><a class="1">Button 1</a></li>
<li><a class="2">Button 2</a></li>
<li><a class="3">Button 3</a></li>
<li><a class="4">Button 4</a></li>
<li><a class="5">Button 5</a></li>
</div>
<div class="B">
   <div class="C"></div>
   <div class="D"></div>
</div>
```

Any solution (CSS or jQuery - though I would prefer a CSS one) will be highly appreciated.

And again an outline of my problem: **[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zcx2LjsL/3/)**

Comment: It's difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve, especially with ambiguous class names. Can you attach an illustration or a sketch to show the desired behavior?

Comment: As far as I can understand, you need to use div B as a container for where all the other lists would appear. Don't add 'display:none' to it however. Add further div classes within it each for each list section of the corresponding original links to expand from. Assign an id to each div wrapping the corresponding list and call them via some JS to display the correct one and hide the rest.

Comment: I think its better to say what you trying to do with example .. like when I click on button1 I want .... and so on .. Its good to let us know what's in your mind

Comment: Sorry, guys! So it should work like this: when mouse over (hover) one button (for example "Button 1") in the div.B should become visible div.C. When mouse over (hover) other button (Button2), in the div.B should become visible div.D and so on. Sorry for the "display:none" on B. It supposed to bo in the inside div.C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this what you try to achieve? You can run the snippet to see the result.

**EDIT:** I have added a class **active** to the first `<li>` element (Button 1), this way it is by default active. You can then add the class **active** to other buttons in other pages.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #efefef;
}

ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #d9d9d9;
}

ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover{
    background: #555;
}

ul .options {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: lightblue;
    z-index: 0;
}

ul li:hover .options{
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) .options {
    background: lightblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) .options {
    background: lightgreen;
}
   
    ul .active {
        background: #555;
    }

    ul .active .options {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="AB">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="1">Button 1</a>
            <div class="options">Button 1 sub-menu</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="2">Button 2</a>
            <div class="options">Button 2 sub-menu</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="3">Button 3</a>
            <div class="options">Button 3 sub-menu</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="4">Button 4</a>
            <div class="options">Button 4 sub-menu</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="5">Button 5</a>
            <div class="options">Button 5 sub-menu</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is the closest answer.  Though, I still have one issue. In the initial state I need Button1 to be hovered and its sub-menu visible (opened) and only after the other button to change the sub-menus according to their buttons. Can you help?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. If I am right you want to open the **sub-menu 1** once you are hover **button 1**, and then?

Comment: I have also edited the background colors of the sub-menus so you can see better how they change.

Comment: I mean when the page/menu loads the first button (Button 1) to be active and its sub-menu visible.

Comment: Ok, so do you want Button 1 to be always active even when the user is not on the menu and to change when user goes on the other options?

Comment: I have updated once again, let me know if now it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

First what you want to do is nest your divs you want to display on hover inside of the list item elements so they become part of the hover field and are target-able by the css traversing. You set the initial display on your nested divs to display: none. On hover, you just set the display on the nested div to inline-block (or any visible display property). I mocked up your code quick to show you.

HTML

```
<div class="AB">
<li><a class="1">Button 1</a>
    <div class="sub">Some stuff</div>
</li>
<li><a class="2">Button 2</a>
    <div class="sub">Some other stuff</div>
</li>
<li><a class="3">Button 3</a></li>
<li><a class="4">Button 4</a></li>
<li><a class="5">Button 5</a></li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.AB {
float:left;
width: 100px;
height:100px;
background: #d9d9d9;
}
.AB li {
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
}
li a{
width: 100px !important;
cursor: pointer;
}
.sub {
display:none;
background: #333;
margin-left: 100px;
width: 400px;
}
.AB li:hover{
background: #555;
}
.AB li:hover > .sub {
display:block;
}
.AB .B {
display: inline-block;
}

.example{
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background: #00ff00;
}

.AB .example {display: inline-block;}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcx2LjsL/14/)

Comment: This a good answer, too. Thanks, buddy! I'll give it a try. :D